# Selenium: Run Automation code with different URL for three environments

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have an automation testing framework in Java. I need this code run on multiple environment such as SIT, UAT and Prod but all of these environment have different URL.

**sit-config.properties**

hompepage = XXX

**uat-config.properties**

homepage = YYY

**Maven Profile**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>sit</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>sit</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>
    <!-- mvn -Denvironment=sit clean test -->

    <profile>
        <id>uat</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>environment</name>
                <value>uat</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
    </profile>

  </profiles>
```

I got an example for Java Owner library but for testng not Maven.
http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-execute-tests-in-multiple-environments/

**Questions**: 
How to integrate Java Owner library with maven profile?

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a different data properties file for the different environment sit, uat and prod. Actually, you do not need to create a separate profile for each execution environment. Follow this:

1: Create a global property at the beginning of the pom. Lets name of the property is property file and give it a default name like sit-config.properties

```
<properties>
    <propertyFile>sit-config.properties</propertyFile>
</properties>
```

2: Update the reader logic to read file name from the system property like

```
System.getProperty("propertyFile");
```

3: Now you can pass the file name from the command line like

```
mvn clean test -DpropertyFile=uat-config.properties
```

Comment: What if i have three property File? sit-config.properties, uat-config.properties and prod-config.properties.

Comment: It can run for n number of files. You only need to set -DpropertyFile={name of your file} at run time in the maven command.

Comment: Actually, the value giving in the maven command will eventually replace the value mentioned in the pom file at run time

Comment: The step 1 seems useless because it overridden at runtime by maven command. Can I skip it?

Comment: no actually its create a runtime variable for you and initialize it with a default value.If you dont wish to do so, then you need to use System.setProperty("propertyFile","name of file")